datafactory API JSON not recognizing changing object
In datafactory I am trying to write from API to blobstorage in JSON, but there is a problem when importing schema.
I have an object in the JSON return output that sometimes is like this:
"answered_by":[]

sometimes like this
"answered_by":[{"contact":{"id":"blablabla","account_id":"blablabla","title":"","first_name":"b","preposition":"","last_name":"b","display_name":"","company":"b","department":"","job_title":"","skype":"","twitter":"","facebook":"","website":"","reference_id":"1b79b44-a03b108","user_id":null,"created_at":"2023-12-07T11:47:53.000Z","updated_at":"2024-01-23T22:59:44.000Z","linkedin":"","integration_id":""}}]

and sometimes like this:
"answered_by":[{"number":"3904928923"}]

Now for some reason it only recognizes the first second method with the contact stuff and not when it just says answered by number. Now i want to return number when contact not know but the schema does not recognize it.
Help would be appreciated!
This is an example of json

But the results can vary so for example answered by can have an entire contact or it can just be a number and from can be a contact but can also just be a number.


what is your expected output JSON structure? Is it should be same as input API JSON structure everytime or you want to change it?

it should change as the api is paginated and the api follows per page structure: items, total_count, page, per_page. And the resulting json from blob storage will be going in a sql table so i dont want to add page and per_page everytime so i cant just keep the input the same as output @RakeshGovindula

Can you provide the expected outputs for every kind of JSON?

I added an example in the question @RakeshGovindula


Click Import schemas in the mapping section to import the schemas from the source Json.



If Import schemas is not recognizing the input data correctly, you can manually edit the column name in the mapping section.

Give the source column as $['answered_by'][0]['number'] in the mapping and give the required sink column name.


